# Include OpenCV directory in YOLOv3 darknet (AlexeyAB) installation in cmake

Tags: cmake, path, darknet, nvidia-jetson

I am trying to link OpenCV to the darknet directory. 
I am working with a Nvidia Jetson AGX Xavier (Ubuntu 18.04). Until recently OpenCV was installed by JetPack in the directory /usr. With this configuration the real time detection of darknet (https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet) with a webcam was working.

I had to renew the installation of OpenCV and now its directory is home/user/OpenCV. I could not include it in the previous directory because of missing permissions. 
Now, every time I start the real time detection of darknet with the command

```
./darknet detector demo cfg/coco.data cfg/yolov3.cfg yolov3.weights -c 0
```

I recieve this error log:

```
./darknet: error while loading shared libraries: libopencv_highgui.so.3.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

When I recompile darknet (cmake, make, install) I receive another error message:

```
Demo needs OpenCV for webcam images.
```

So I assume, that OpenCV is not included in the compilation and darknet does not find the libraries. 
I tested this options:

- In the Makefile of darknet OPENCV=1 is included (double checked, totally sure, that this is not the fault)
- I tried to export the path of OpenCV to its previous path e.g. with export OpenCV_DIR=/usr/share/OpenCV
- I tried to link the path e.g. with LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib
  or LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/share
- I think there could be a possibility to include the OpenCV path in some file related to cmake. In the CmakeLists.txt file is the line

```
  set(PThreads_windows_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/3rdparty/pthreads CACHE PATH "Path where pthreads for windows can be located")
endif()
set(Stb_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/3rdparty/stb CACHE PATH "Path where Stb image library can be located")

set(CMAKE_DEBUG_POSTFIX d)
set(CMAKE_THREAD_PREFER_PTHREAD ON)
find_package(Threads REQUIRED)
if(MSVC)
  find_package(PThreads_windows REQUIRED)
endif()
if(ENABLE_OPENCV) 
  if(OpenCV_FOUND)
    if(SELECT_OPENCV_MODULES)
```

I think here or maybe somewhere else I should include the new directory path to OpenCV. I tried with find_package or set_path, but I am not sure if this was the right point to enter this option. Also I have no file called finOpencv.cmake.

Does someone have an idea, how i could 'tell' darknet, where OpenCV is located?

If you need further information, I will be happy to share.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Edit: If I include Find_Package(OpenCV) in CMakeLists.txt and recompile, I recieve this output:

```
  CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:96 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindOpenCV.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "OpenCV", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "OpenCV" with any
  of the following names:

    OpenCVConfig.cmake
    opencv-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "OpenCV" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "OpenCV_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "OpenCV"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
```

Comment: "So I assume, that OpenCV is not included in the compilation and darknet does not find the libraries." - You can easy check whether OpenCV is found or not by reading output of `cmake` running. If CMake cannot find OpenCV, then it should be a message about that, with instructions how to fix the problem. By the way, include this message into your question post. "I tried to export the path of OpenCV to its **previous** path e.g. with `export OpenCV_DIR=/usr/share/OpenCV`" - You want to use **new** OpenCV installation but set variable to the **old** path. Why??

Comment: Thanks for your hint. I also tried export OPENCV_DIR=/home/username/OpenCV and OPENCV_DIR=/home/username/OpenCV/lib (where libopencv_highgui.so.3.3 is located) but no difference. 
Normally I did not see a note for OpenCV not found (Maybe because in the code is written 'if(OpenCV_Found)'?). 
If I include this in CMakelists.txt 
 if(ENABLE_OPENCV)
  find_package(OpenCV)
I recieve the output I will add in my main post.

Comment: "OPENCV_DIR=/home/username/OpenCV/lib (where libopencv_highgui.so.3.3 is located)" - Have you ever read the error message? It says: "... or set "OpenCV_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.". You need to set `OpenCV_DIR` variable to the directory which contains either `OpenCVConfig.cmake` or `opencv-config.cmake` file. Whether a directory contains `libopencv_highgui.so.3.3` or other library files are completely unrelated.

Comment: BTW, original `CMakeLists.txt` **already has** the call `find_package(OpenCV)` at [line 96](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L96). It looks weird that you cite the code without it. I would suggest you to re-load this file from the repo and do not modify it after that.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. 
I had to backup the system (because of some other reason), so I can't tell right now, if it works.

Answer (score 0):

> Edit: If I include Find_Package(OpenCV) in CMakeLists.txt and recompile, I recieve this output

It's good. And as a next step in darknet build directory:

```
 cmake . -DOpenCV_DIR=/usr/share/OpenCV
```